# azure cli get individual blob (file) size list

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I have been using the command:

```
az storage blob directory list --account-name ${a} --account-key ${k} -c ${container} -d path/${yyyymmdd}  --query [].name --output_table
```

Which will list the files available in a particular blob. However, I also want the file sizes. Digging around it seems:

```
az vm list --resource-group QueryDemo --query "sort_by([].{Name:name, Size:storageProfile.osDisk.diskSizeGb}, &Size)" --output table
```

should sort the files by size and also list the file sizes. I do not mind if things are sorted, therefore, I have been trying:

```
az storage blob directory list --account-name ${a} --account-key ${k} -c ${container} -d path/${yyyymmdd}  --query "[].{Name:name, Size:storageProfile.osDisk.diskSizeGb}" --output_table
```

to no avail. Is listing the file size along with the name possible with az cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
az storage blob directory list --account-name ${a} --account-key ${k} -c ${container} -d path/${yyyymmdd}  --query "[].{name:name, size:properties.contentLength}" --output table
```